# Segmentation fault from sscanf in a loop in C

Tags: c, string, file, segmentation-fault, scanf

I have a problem with this piece of code:

FILE *parziale=fopen("media1","w");

```
complex z;
char  * strings = calloc(__MAX_LEN__, sizeof(char));
k=0;
i=0;
z.re=0;
z.im=0;
int *nhit_s=calloc(nsrc+1,sizeof(int)); 

nhit_s[nsrc]= const;

for(;feof(prova)==0;){

    strings = fgets(strings, __MAX_LEN__, prova);

    if(cancelletto(strings)&&(strings != NULL)){

        do{ 

            strings = fgets(strings, __MAX_LEN__, prova);

            //  fprintf(parziale,"%d\t%s\n",i,strings);

            z.re+=readCompl(strings).re;
            z.im+=readCompl(strings).im;

            i++;

        }while( i % nhit_s[nsrc] != 0);


            i=0;
            z.re /= nhit_s[nsrc];
            z.im /= nhit_s[nsrc];
            //  printf("%d\n",k);
            fprintf(parziale,"%d\t%lf\t%lf\n",k,z.re,z.im);
            z.re=0;
            z.im=0;
            k++;

    }

}
```

the loop should read the rows of a  FILE pointed by "prova", if the row starts with # it enters the second loop which sums the rows between the first and the second # and then it saves the result on another file pointed by "parziale". The function readCompl(strings) is defined as follows:

complex readCompl(char * str){

```
int n, m;
complex z;
sscanf(str,"%d\t%d\t%lf\t%lf", &n, &m, &(z.re), &(z.im));
return z;
```

}

the problem is that after a certain number of iterations i get a segmentation fault which i checked comes from the function readCompl(strings), i have no idea why since the function just reads from "prova" and should not have any problems. Does anyone have an idea why i get this segmentation fault?

Comment: Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Images are not a good idea in a question. Cannot copy'n'paste them. Bad for mobile devices

Comment: Do not post your code as image. Post your code directly in the question as **text**, please.

Comment: I'm really sorry, i have been careless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `feof()` is a bad idea as it can return zero, and then the next line of input can encounter end of the file - which can give unexpected errors

Also `fgets()` returns `NULL` if an error occurs, including encountering end of file.

Imagine your loop has been going along happily, and has just read the second last line in the file.   On the next iteration, `feof()` will return zero, so the first statement `strings = fgets(strings, __MAXLEN__, prova)` will succeed.   The second one - inside the `do-while` loop - will set `strings` to `NULL`, so will pass the `NULL` to your `readCompl()` function - which will, in turn, try to read from the `NULL` using `sscanf()`.    `sscanf()` gives undefined behaviour if given a `NULL` - (one symptom of which can be a segmentation violation - the program accessing memory it shouldn't).

The solution needs to be in two parts.   Firstly, don't use `feof()` to control any loop.  Second, check the result of functions you call (`fgets()`, `sscanf()`, etc) and - if you need to - use their return value to control loops.

Comment: thank you very much you gave me the correct hint to solve the problem!